# Visual Studio 2015 Convert.ToDouble gives error while trying to watch lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I am giving VS 2015 a try, and as everybody knows one of the coolest feature is the ability to watch lambda expressions in the watch window.

I created a console app to test this and here is the code for that.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WatchLambdaExpressions
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var books = new List<Book>() {new Book()
            {
                Author="J.K.Rowling",
                Rating="5",
                Title="Harry Potter"
            },
            new Book()
            {
                Author="Baroness Orczy",
                Rating = "4.8",
                Title="Scarlet Pimpernell"
            },
            new Book()
            {
                Author = "J.R.R.Tolkein",
                Rating="5",
                Title="Lord of the Rings"
            },
            new Book()
            {
                Author="Alexander Dumas",
                Rating="4.9",
                Title="Count of Monte Cristo"
            },
            new Book()
            {
                Author="Robert Ludlum",
                Title = "Bourne Identity",
                Rating = "4.6"
            }
            };

            var selectedBooks = books.Where(b => Convert.ToDouble(b.Rating) >= 4.8);

        }
    }

    public class Book
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Author { get; set; }

        public string Rating { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I run the program in debug mode and have a breakpoint right at the point of exit of the Main method.

Ok, now I go to the watch window and write :

```
books.Where(b => Convert.ToDouble(b.Rating) >= 4.8)
```

I expected the above to evaluate and filter and show me a list of books where rating >= 4.8 , but it shows

> Error: The debugger is unable to evaluate this expression

Do you have any idea why ?

I am able to watch for other lambda expressions though.

This works just fine :

```
books.Where(b => b.Title.Contains("Harry"))
```

Comment: Does the `String` always contain a valid number? `Convert.ToDouble` will throw an exception otherwise.

Comment: Yes sir, it always contains a valid number. I am creating the list myself and have full control over the data.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 hs fixed this. So I consider this solved. Thanks